# Is it possible to put the help icons in p:accordionPanel header?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accordion, accordionpane

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2 and JSF for developing pages but I couldn't add search icon and other links in Accordion panel header?

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
    <p:tab title="Sample Accordion Panel1 for ABC_UX My Chronical">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <h:outputText styleClass="UX_FontClass" value="The Story Begins with ABC_UX R and D Works My Chronicle..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

How can I use the search and help icons in `<p:accordionPanel>` header?

Comment: I've attached my sample code also.
 <p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true">
 <p:tab title="Sample Accordion Panel1 for ABC_UX My Chronical">
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
 <h:outputText styleClass="UX_FontClass" value="The Story Begins with ABC_UX R and D Works My Chronicle..." />
 </h:panelGrid> </p:tab> </<p:accordionPanel>

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost 100% sure there was an answer here (otherwise it could not be marked as being the target of a duplicate)

No this is not possible. Your best bet is to take the PrimeFaces source. Add an option facet to the tab like the normal panel has and use that.