# How to customize p:accodionPanel icon?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accordion

I'm using PrimeFaces with JSF and I am trying to customize the `<p:accordionPanel>` and add more icons in `<p:accordionPanel>` header.

How can I achieve those two? Below is my sample code.

```
<p:accordionPanel dynamic="true" cache="true" activeIndex="none">
    <p:tab title="Sample Accordion Panel1 for  Chronicle">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <h:outputText styleClass="UX_FontClass" value="My Chronicle..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: Do you just want to change left / down arrow?

Comment: yes but i found the solution for that. I need to add more icons in accodionPanel header like notification icon,history icons.

Comment: Have you tried icons wrapped in p:tab tag? You can set position through style.

Comment: Can you please stick to your original question... You've already asked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050221/is-it-possible-to-put-the-help-icons-in-accordion-panel-header

Comment: If you can't seem to find your previously asked questions back, then click on the profile picture in the top bar, or anywhere your username appears as a link. It'll lead you to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3114967) where you can find [all previously asked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3114967?tab=questions).